# PHPMailer - Having multiple $_POST's in Body

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is what I have:`

```
<?php
require("/Library/WebServer/Documents/phpmailer/PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "host";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "email@email.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "email@email.com";
$mail->FromName = $_POST["name"];

$mail->AddAddress("other@other.com");                  // name is optional


$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML


$mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
$mail->Body = $_POST["one"];

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>`
```

I'm trying to have multiple $_POST's in the body of the email because I want to have form inputs from a HTML document.

For example, I want in the body for it to have the inputs from "one", and any more, but when I try and put multiple $_POST's after the $mail->Body it does not work.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
$mail->Body = $_POST["one"].$_POST["two"];
```

This uses a period to separate the different variables, or you could use:

```
$mail->Body = $_POST["one"];
$mail->Body .= $_POST["two"];
```

This uses a  `.=`  to add to the existing Body.

Comment: Thank you, but how could I add a line break between each variable? I tried using \n but it did not work for me.

Comment: You would want `$_POST["one"]."\n".$_POST["two"];` as you need to have the \n surrounded by double quotes.  Or in my second example  `$mail->Body .= "\n".$_POST["two"];`

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way...

```
$mail->Body = "This is starting ".{addslashes($_POST['one'])}. " This is Two. ".{addslashes($_POST['two'])}." This is END";
```

or

```
$mail->Body = "This is starting";
$mail->Body .= addslashes(trim($_POST['one']));
$mail->Body .= " This is Two. ";
$mail->Body .= addslashes(trim($_POST['two']));
$mail->Body .= "This is END";
```

'.' (DOT) works as concatenation operator. Make sure to check for any SQL INJECTION.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->Body = $_POST["one"] . $_POST["two"] . $_POST["three"];
```

or better, maybe:

```
$one = isset($_POST["one"]) ? $_POST["one"] : NULL;
$two = isset($_POST["two"]) ? $_POST["two"] : NULL;
$three = isset($_POST["three"]) ? $_POST["three"] : NULL;
$body = $one . $two . $three;
$mail->Body = $body;
```

PHP String Concatenation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the `$_POST` fields together into one string which is then passed to `$mail->Body` using the php concatenation operator `.` like so:

```
$mail->Body = $_POST['one'].$_POST['two'].$_POST['three']; // etc...
```